# Parsing complicated Json Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have a json array:

```
{
 "array":[
      {
       "Name_0":"Value_0",
       "Name_1":"Value_1"
      },
      {
       "Name_2":"Value_2",
       "Name_3":"Value_3",
       "Name_4":"Value_4",
       "Name_5":"Value_5"
      }
 ]
}
```

The data structures inside the json array are not consistent.
How can I parse them in C#?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this will be

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var data = serializer
    .Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>>(input);
```

This is because your json data structure is like this.  For innermost element we have a `Dictionary<string, string>` which is nested in a generic list which in turn is nested in another generic dictionary.