# How to extract JSON data received in controller in a String variable

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

Could you please let me know how to extract JSON data received in a string variable in controller. Please see the attachment.Thanks.

[image: image showing json data received in controller]

```
 $("#btn1").on("click", function () {
    var i = new Array();
    var j = 0;
    $("#sl1").multiselect("getChecked").map(function () {
        alert(this.value);
        i.push(this.value);
        //i[j] = this.value;                     
        //j++;

    }).get();
    var postData = { values: i };
    jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
    $.post('/TodoList/searchdata', postData, function (data) {

        alert(data.Result);
    });
    //$.ajax({
    //    type: "POST",
    //    url: "/TodoList/searchdata",
    //    data: postData,
    //    success: function (data) {
    //        alert(data.Result);
    //    },
    //    dataType: "json",
    //    traditional: true
    //});

});
```

### Controller code:-

```
public void searchdata(String[] values)
    {
    //{
    //    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    //   List<String[][]> data=js.Deserialize<List<String[][]>>(i);
        Console.WriteLine(values);

    }
```

Comment: You need to show your code (including the ajax). And you should be binding it to a model (not a `string`)

Comment: $("#btn1").on("click", function () {
        var i = new Array();
        var j = 0;
        $("#sl1").multiselect("getChecked").map(function () {
            alert(this.value);
            i.push(this.value);
            //i[j] = this.value;                     
            //j++;
                
        }).get();
        var postData = { values: i };
        jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
        $.post('/TodoList/searchdata', { i: postData }, function (data) {

            alert(data.Result);
        });

Comment: Edit your question, not in comments (impossible to read when you dont even format it). And include the controller signature (and delete the image)

Comment: I did that. Please find the attached code.

Comment: It appears your passing an array of strings so it should be `$.post('/TodoList/searchdata', postData, function (data) {` and the parameter should be `string[] values`

Comment: it didn't help. Do you have another solution?

Comment: I will create a Fiddle for your shortly

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen. It really helps me.

Comment: Just test the code from my previous comment and it works for me. Did you change the `$.post()` code as per my last comment as well? - the parameter is `values` is correctly bound with the array.

Comment: another question asked today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34823400/parsing-complicated-json-array-in-c-sharp/34823448#34823448 seems everybody is into parsing today :)

Comment: Please see my changed code @Stephen

Comment: I have edited code please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft Json library https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

So As mentioned in the below link use it like below

> string json = @"{    'Email': 'james@example.com',    'Active': true, 
>   'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',   'Roles': [
>        'User',    'Admin'    ]  }";
>
> Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

if you doesn't have model , just use like below

> var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

the check the below link

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var data=js.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Class :

```
public class JsonAttributeClass<T> where T:class ,new()
{
   public static string EntityToJsonConvertor(T entity)
   {
       string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity);
       return json;

   }

   public static T JsonToEntityConvertor(string json)
   {
       var entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
       return entity;
   }
}
```